# ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople gives wrong vcard format

Tags: ios7

If address book record name contains special characters (for example ";") then `ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople` returns wrong VCard format.

For example, if address book contains contact named `Test4 -/\;())₹&&[}#^**`
then it gives following VCard format:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 7.0.4//EN
N:-/\;())₹&&[}#^**;Test4;;;
FN:Test4 -/\;())₹&&[}#^**
TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE;type=pref:444444
E**ND:VCABEGIN:VCARD**
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 7.0.4//EN
N:;Test6;;;
FN:Test6
TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE;type=pref:5555555
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Can you please share the code which you are using to generate vcf file... it will be more explainable to answer your question...